# Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

In my React app, I have the following useEffect and cleanup.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (pageLoad) {     
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (e) => {
            localStorage.removeItem(SOME_KEY);
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('beforeunload');
        }
    }
}, [pageLoad]);
```

However, I get the following error. Is there some issue with the removeEventListener ?

```
Failed to execute 'removeEventListener' on 'EventTarget': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass same function to [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#syntax)

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (pageLoad) {
    const cb = (e) => {
      localStorage.removeItem(SOME_KEY);
    };
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cb);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cb);
    };
  }
}, [pageLoad]);
```